# failed Task of Azure cosmos Db emulator in Azure Devops yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am trying to test my unit test cases with Azure Cosmos Db emulator. When I ran the task , the pipeline gave me error as target machine actively refused and all queries which was supposed to be tested ran against my actual production db. Probably the error was pipeline was unable to connect to my emulator db. To fix this I add Azure Cosmos Db Emulator task(public preview) from the list of task and added the below two tasks in my YAMl pipeline. I get the below error in my Pipeline for task Run Azure Cosmos Db emulator:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint
> azure-cosmosdb-emulator on network nat: failed during
> hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access
> the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)
> Error: failed to start containers:
> 11429cb294f98fe04cac2fbc8ff026063ee51d2dff4ece1bbeff33c778cdd4da

Below is my Yaml script:

```
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
              Start-CosmosDbEmulator
              Get-Module
        - task: azure-cosmosdb.emulator-public-preview.run-cosmosdbemulatorcontainer.CosmosDbEmulator@2
          displayName: 'Run Azure Cosmos DB Emulator'

        - script: yarn test
          displayName: 'Run API tests (Cosmos DB)'
          env:
            HOST: $(CosmosDbEmulator.Endpoint)
            AUTH_KEY: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
            NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: '0'
```

What wrong am i doing? if anyone can explain. if I dont use the Powershell task I get the below error:

> Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem
> 120a874376d885ffea38a4e299f613340a599eae8a01b691366f21dcb6707501: The
> container operating system does not match the host operating system.

Comment: In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231589/3744182) that may be deleted, [Oury-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15262014/oury-msft) writes, *Same question posted on GitHub:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/77679 currently under investigation.*